# Importing a UTF-8 CSV File into a DataGridView in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, csv, datagridview, oledb

I'm trying to use the below code to import a CSV file with UTF-8 encoding into a DataGridView in my app so that all the characters show correctly.

The problem I am getting is a 'C:\Users\spald\Desktop\orders-2016-08-18.csv' is not a valid path error. The file is definitely there, at that path. Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong? Alternatively, I just need a quick and easy way to import a UTF-8 csv file into a DataGrid View if anyone knows an easier way.

Thanks :)

```
    Dim myDataTable As New DataTable
    Dim myConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=""Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"";Data Source=""C:\Users\spald\Desktop\orders-2016-08-18.csv"";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited""")
    Dim myAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [orders-2016-08-18$]", myConnection)
    myAdapter.Fill(myDataTable)
    dgvFirst.DataSource = myDataTable
```

Comment: Use just the folder location on the connection string and then the filename in the SQL SELECT statement.

Comment: Hi @Plutonix, that worked great :) but it's still not recognising the file as UTF-8. How can I specify the encoding?